# Android Studio project ignore by KIS antivirus

Tags: android, android-studio, kaspersky

I use Kaspersky Internet Security on my PC. Some time ago I started receiving such alert:

```
Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories: 
C:\Users\Andrew\.AndroidStudio3.5\system
D:\Android Development\jobnet-android
C:\Users\Andrew\.gradle
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

I have added these folders to antivirus ignore list but I still continue receiving this alert. Maybe I did smth wrong and I have to add these paths to some another lists. I also saw some questions and links like [that](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560-Antivirus-Impact-on-Build-Speed). At every link which I saw all suggestions are connected with Windows Defender but I think that it is turned off. Maybe someone knows how to fix this alert?

Comment: I found this thread on Kaspersky forum: https://community.kaspersky.com/kaspersky-internet-security-13/your-anti-virus-program-might-have-impact-on-performance-of-android-studio-3367
it might help you

Comment: @saeed, I saw this thread and also did all things from this thread, but I still receive alert message :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching this that is using ESET:
Setup -> Computer -> Real Time Protection -> Configure -> Process Exclusions

Add Android Studio in here.

I had this problem today and this seems to have fixed it so far.

Comment: Kaspersky isn't ESET.

Answer (score 1):

My Kaspersky is in german, so the wording may not be accurate:

```
Settings -> 
Threats and Exclusions (it's the 3rd menu-item) ->
configure exclusions (next to thumbs-up symbol).

I entered all suggested directories and just excluded the component AMSI- 
protection for each.
```

Although I don't have a real clue it seems to work (no warning / fast build).
Feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

If you have also Windows Defender on your PC you will need to add those folders to exceptions under:

> "Windows Security->Virus and threat protection->Exclusions->Add or remove exclusions"

That worked for me and I also have a third party antivirus, ESET, but I think the process is the same for Kaspersky

Comment: he is clearly mentioned that he is aware of Windows Defender and his Windows Defender is off!

Comment: Defender doesn't do anything if you use a 3rd-party antivirus.